# Flatpak apps not showing up in app menu

Tags: thirdpartyapps, flatpak

I've installed two Flatpak apps with sideload, and they never got icons and I cannot start them. What should I do? It was Spotify and Discord. Is this a general limitation of elementary OS?

Edit: The apps worked fine until I closed them

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is probably a bug that will be fixed soon. In the meantime you can launch Flatpak applications from the terminal. First execute

```
flatpak list
```

to get the list of you applications. Then run your chosen application (ie. `org.example.app`) by

```
flatpak run org.example.app
```

---

If you want to add the application to your application menu by hand, you need to find its `.desktop` file and copy it to `~/.local/share/applications`:

```
cd ~/.local/share/flatpak/app
cd org.example.app
cd current/active/files/share/applications/
cp -a . ~/.local/share/applications
```

Icons should appear in the Application Menu immediately.

Comment: Since flatpaks are installed on a per-user basis, it would make more sense to copy the .desktop file to the `~/.local/share/applications` folder, instead of the `/usr/share/applications`. No broken icon for the other users this way.

Comment: @VladPop Thanks, I edited the answer accordingly.

Comment: Thanks for the help. It worked great when I found the right .desktop file!